Pressure at a point around the corner in a conical fask
I have gone through this two very informative links in understanding pressure.
Weight of fluid in a conical container act entirely on the base?
Pressure is isotropic
But in a long conical flask which is being filled by fluid till neck and is having a height h:
             |  |
            /    \
           /      \
          /        \
         /          \
        /            \
       /              \
      /                \
     /                  \
    / C     A   B        \
    ----------------------

The pressure at point A and B is same and is isotropic, since that maintains the equilibrium, resisting shear stress to a static liquid.
Also, the pressure at point C is also same as A, according to Fluid Pressure as if we think a block of fluid between A and C. The change in momentum caused by the Brownian Motion of the Fluid particles is equal and opposite at point A and C because the fluid is static.
But I am finding hard to explain this. In my understanding, the resultant change in momentum caused by Brownian Motion at point C and directed towards A is equal to A and is $\rho g h$. But since pressure is isotropic the same amount of pressure is being exerted at every direction so the same amount of pressure is exerted upwards by the fluid at point C. But that upward pressure is $\rho g h$, is not supporting a weight of the fluid equal to $\rho g h$ that is, the height of the water level at point C is not $h$. So the upward fluid pressure should not be equal to what is there at point A. Where I am getting wrong?

You have forgotten the effect of the walls of your container. Pressure at base of 3 different dam designs and Understanding Hydrostatic Pressure on a Microscopic Scale $\dots$

$\dots$ Is the vertical pressure force on the bottom of a liquid container equal the weight of the fluid above the surface area?

@JonCuster I have mentioned the link to my question itself. But still I am confusing it. Maybe the links from Farcher will help

@Farcher any link in Stack overflow or blogs? to understand in more detail how the shear force is adding into it. I am not able to understands with those links.
